# How can I decode a string read from file?

Tags: python, string, encoding

I read an file into a string in Python, and it shows up as encoded (not sure the encoding).

```
query = ""
with open(file_path) as f:
 for line in f.readlines():
   print(line)
   query += line
query
```

The lines all print out in English as expected

```
select * from table
```

but the query at the end shows up like

```
ÿþd\x00r\x00o\x00p\x00 \x00t\x00a\x00b\x00l\x00e\x00
```

What's going on?

Comment: From HTML entities to Unicode-text I get `Ã¿Ã¾drop table`

Comment: Ack the contents of the query are supposed to be confidential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreed with Carlos, the encoding seems to be UTF-16LE. There seems to be BOM present, thus `encoding="utf-16"` would be able to autodetect if it's little- or big-endian.

Idiomatic Python would be:

```
with open(file_path, encoding="...") as f:
    for line in f:
        # do something with this line
```

In your case, you append each line to query, thus entire code can be reduced to:

```
query = open(file_path, encoding="...").read()
```

Comment: Accepted answer as it's the only one that works for me in Python 3.6.  Also appreciate reducing it to one line of code

Answer (score 2):

It seems like UTF-16 data.
Can you try decoding it with utf-16?

```
with open(file_path) as f:
    query=f.decode('utf-16')
print(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(filePath) as f:
    fileContents =  f.read()
    if isinstance(fileContents, str):
        fileContents = fileContents.decode('ascii', 'ignore').encode('ascii') #note: this removes the character and encodes back to string.
    elif isinstance(fileContents, unicode):
        fileContents = fileContents.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```